# How to open the history of a project in source control quickly?

Tags: tfs

I try to record a macro so that I can quickly open the History of my project in Source Control but the macro when played raises an error "Object variable or With block variable not set".

How can I get rid of that and make the macro work? Or is there any other way to do it? Please help!

Nam.

[Edit]
The steps recorded in my macro: Open Team Explorer - Open Source Control - Right click a project - Select History.

Comment: Do you want to help support the Visual Studio ALM community on Stack Exchange? http://bit.ly/caQ9ds

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/)?

This comes with a History Sidekick that is realy poswerfull and most likely shows what you need.

[image]
**Figure: Easily view the history of any project**

It also would be pretty easy to build a custom tool using the TFS SDK that displayed the history any way you choose.

Answer (score 0):

I recorded this macro. Works fine for me, except a "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component" error :) but opens the history

```
 Sub TemporaryMacro()
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("View.TeamExplorer")
        DTE.Windows.Item("{131369F2-062D-44A2-8671-91FF31EFB4F4}").Activate() 'Team Explorer
        DTE.ActiveWindow.Object.GetItem("your_tfs_server\your_project\Source Control").Select(vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeSelect)
        DTE.ActiveWindow.Object.DoDefaultAction()
        DTE.Windows.Item("{99B8FA2F-AB90-4F57-9C32-949F146F1914}").Activate() 'Source Control Explorer
        DTE.Windows.Item("{2456BD12-ECF7-4988-A4A6-67D49173F565}").Activate() 'History - $/ProjectName
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.TfsHistory")
    End Sub
```

Comment: So, in my opinion the GUID's may be different per machine or installation. Did you edit this line for your settings? 
DTE.ActiveWindow.Object.GetItem("your_tfs_server\your_project\Source Control").Select(vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeSelect)